# "HTTP 503 - Service Unavailable" when trying to access ADFS password change page from an external network

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office-365, adfs

I'm using ADFS 3.0 federated domain (SSO with Office-365) and I've successfully set up the password change page to work from any workplace joined device. I'm currently trying to set it up to be accessible from any device not joined to the workplace.

I applied the hotfix as mentioned in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samueld/archive/2015/05/13/adfs-2012-r2-now-supports-password-change-not-reset-across-all-devices.aspx) article:

> Note: ADFS 2012 R2 required authenticated/registered devices (a.k.a
>   ‘workplace join’) to allow the change of passwords. Based on customer
>   feedback, we have relaxed this constraint and allow this from all
>   devices. You will need to apply 3035025 hotfix on all the ADFS
>   servers.

But when I try to access the password change page from out of the corporate network: `https://adfs.mydomain.com/adfs/portal/updatepassword`

I get an error :

> HTTP 503 - Service Unavailable

Any advice how to fix this ?

EDIT:

Just want to add that I can access adfs.mydomain.com and it shows the Welcome page for IIS

Comment: Additional information of an HTTP 503 response should be available in the event logs and/or with detailed errors enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is older so I have to make some assumptions here.  It's stated it doesn't work outside the network, but implies it does work inside the network.

Typically inside the firewall you will connect directly to ADFS servers.  From outside you are connecting thru a proxy device. Probably a good chance the issue is with whatever proxy device you are using and how you have ADFS published.